# How to normalize database table where there are plural and singular words?

Tags: sql, asp.net, datatable, trim

I have many words and their scores in my sql database .I wonder if there is a sql query to solve my problem.So db table is similar to this

```
word scores
pen    5
book   10
school 12
books   7
```

so I would like to sum up the scores of book and books and delete the books and have my table like this;

```
word scores
pen    5
book   17
school 12
```

I have asp.net web project that is connected my sql database,Do you think it is possible to do?

Comment: Unless you have only a few unique words this is going to be tricky. SQL databases aren't really built for robust text search. You might have to consider using a text search database like elasticsearch or Sphinx.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

Do you have a table of mappings for singular words and plural words?

First, not all plurals follow a simple pattern:  goose/geese, he/they, stratum/strata, person/people, etc.

Second, not all words ending in "s" are necessarily plural  For instance, "woods" refers to a forest, not necessarily the plural of "wood".  And "shorts" and "mathematics" are singular.

Comment: I see but I just would like to do it for words like book/books ,penguin/penguins. There is a method called string contain in c# ,I wonder if there is somethings similar in sql